# Upload Image by ajax gives unsupported media type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload an image to my server using jquery. I need to send image, filename and file url to backend. There for I have added these three fields in "data" (refer code). I am doing it like this(below  code) but I am getting error in console saying "unsupported media file" 415. How should I solve it?

```
posterFile = e.target.files;
        selectedPoster = posterFile[0];


uploadPoster() {
        var blobPosterFile = selectedPoster;   
        console.log("U called me?")
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("fileToUpload", blobPosterFile);

    var that = this;
    let token;
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://www.backend.example.name.com/api/v1/videos/",
        "method": "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        "credentials": 'include',
        "headers": {
            Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
        },
        "data": {
            "Title": selectedFile.name,
            "File": videoURL,
            "Poster": formData
        },
        success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                            console.log("poster uploaded")
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
               });
}
```

I am getting error saying "unsupported media type" 415

Comment: Looks like you are trying to post JSON in which case you should use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: can you post an answer? It will be much helpful. Thanks in advance